# firebase custom events showing (not set) values

Tags: android, firebase-analytics, custom-events

I am sending custom events in my firebase analytics and one of the event's values shows (not set).

I have crossed check everything with logs and all, and the value and parameter name, nothing is going blank for this event, but still, in some cases, it is showing (not set).

```
  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(listdata.get(position).getPersonalizationTitle())){
                    firebaseEvents.createNewEvent("personalization_selection",
                            listdata.get(position).getPersonalizationTitle(), 
                             "category_name");
   }

   public void createNewEvent(String event_name, String title, String values_title) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(values_title) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString(values_title, title);
            firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(event_name, params);
            Log.d("FIREBASE_EVENTS", event_name + "--" + params);
        }
    }
```